# Angular's element.find() can't find nested input elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, element

I'm creating a directive with the following template (simplified):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the directive's link function I want to add listeners to the inputs, but I can't get the input elements. The directive looks like the following:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '<path-to-above-html-file>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var inputs = element.find('input'); // Returning empty JQLite object
        }
    };
});
```

According to the Angular element documentation, the find() method should be able to find nested elements. But why does this not work then?

I've tried to print the element in the console and loop trough all child elements, and the inputs do exist.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try use this`element.querySelector('input')`

Comment: Your directive and `element.find('input')` works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/HIUbDoVbgCShf9OjGnKa

Comment: Thank you. This made me realise that the number of inputs came from a value in a controller, which was loaded after the console.log.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access element,then use `querySelector()`.But beware,querySelector only returns first child element.

If you want to get all elements use `querySelctorAll()` like below

```
element.querySelectorAll("input")
```

Comment: huh? `"input"` is a tag name